# 'Info' class not recognized with Swashbuckle and Swagger libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

Am I missing a package or reference because my `AddSwaggerGen` method does not compile. My code:

I added `using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;`

but this code

```
  services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
   {
     c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });                 
     c.EnableAnnotations();    
   });
```

will not compile:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Info' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Here is the csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="3.10.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub" Version="1.0.0-beta2-18618-05">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="5.0.0-rc2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="5.0.0-rc2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="5.0.0-rc2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="5.0.0-rc2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: please upload your `csproj` file or list your `PackageReference`

Comment: I have added my .csproj

Comment: everything seems alright, I'm afraid to say that I've no idea about it :|

Comment: try chaning this as ```c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo{ Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Info` is deprecated in version 5

It has been replaced with `OpenApiInfo` so you have to reflect that in your swagger setup:

```
c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Version = "1.0", Title = "My API" });
```

Answer (score 8):

Change Info class to OpenApiInfo class.

add using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models

Answer (score 0):

Info is old now and for the latest versions, OpenApiInfo is what is being used. Try something like this and it should hopefully do the job for you.

```
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
   {
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Your-Api", 
    Version = "v1"});
});
```